# Application working in Nexus one but not in Htc hero

Tags: android

I have developed an application in Android2.1 update1. This application transfers the audio from microphone to headphones. This application is working in HTC Nexus One but it is not working in HTC Hero. What could be the problem? Please help me with this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it giving any stake trace?

Comment: as often the phrase "not working" is the best description in the world..

Answer (score 0):

Htc Hero provides Android OS, v1.5 (Cupcake). so you can't run an upgrade version of application in lower versions.

Comment: Actually both mobiles are running on same version Android 2.1